# Python decode TCP from LabVIEW

Tags: python, decode, labview

I am trying to decode data coming via TCP from labview. I want to send 4-bit header denoting the length followed by the message.

My LabVIEW sucessfully send the 4-bytes to the Python. And Python recieves b'\x00\x00\x00\x016' which clearly denotes a byte of information.

How do I then decode the command back to the integer length such that I can have an additional read to read in the rest of the message?

This is my python script:

```
import socket

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(('localhost', 9991))
server.listen(1)

while True:
    conn, addr = server.accept()
    messagelen = conn.recv(4)
    print(messagelen)
    bits = bytes.decode(messagelen)
    print(bits)
    server.close()
```

[LabVIEW script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUBYY.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: You might check out TestScript, a LabVIEW/Python connector from Wineman Technology, now a CertTech company. URL: https://www.winemantech.com/testscript-download It's a source-released fully bidirectional connector; all the TCP stuff is handled already.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your bytes you receive aren't `b'\x00\x00\x00\x16'`? If they are you can use the struct module to unpack.

```
import socket
import struct

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(('localhost', 9991))
server.listen(1)

while True:
    conn, addr = server.accept()
    bits = conn.recv(4)
    messagelen = struct.unpack('>i', bits)[0]
    print(messagelen)
    server.close()
```